# Export Current Working Directory in Mac

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I need to export a variable to point to the current working directory of the script.I know that i can use `pwd` to print the current working directory.But how can i export it ?

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="the script working path"
```

Comment: Do you mean [How to set a BASH variable equal to the output from a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/258523)?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah.How can use it here for pwd command?

Comment: The same way you use it for any other command. Did you read the linked question and the accepted answer? Did you try it?

Comment: @EtanReisner So i use VAR="$(pwd)"

Comment: @EtanReisner Got it.But the double quotes does not come ..VAR=pwd echo "export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$VAR:/usr/lib"

Comment: You don't want the quotes in the variable value. They will only hurt you. The quotes are for the shell that sees the value. They aren't wanted in the value itself. You quote the *expansion* of the variable if you need the expansion to stay as one word. `="$VAR:/usr/lib"`, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner okay.thanks